# Compose compiler error when trying to run tests

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, build.gradle

When I try to run a compose tests, I'm getting this compilation error:

```
This version (1.0.5) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.5.31 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.8.22 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).
```

I can't find anywhere where this 1.0.5 version comes from.

This is my compose build.gradle settings:

```
def composeBom = platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.05.01')
    implementation composeBom
    androidTestImplementation composeBom
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.4.3"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1"
    // Android Studio Preview support
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
```

How can I fix this error please?

Comment: Check your project level build.gradle file. It's in the root directory of your project

Comment: @levi check what?

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.gradle` file, update this,

```
jetpackComposeCompilerVersion = "1.4.3" // Or the required version

composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion jetpackComposeCompilerVersion
}
```

Comment: @Sharas This is the error as per the shared message. Is it still the same error?

Comment: yes, I just wonder where this is coming from